# backpropagation for gender classification model using python

Tags: python, tags, nlp, backpropagation

I have created a model for gender classification using NLTK in python. I am using a feed-forward mechanism. How to incorporate a back propagation method into this?

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import names
import random

def gender_features(word):
    return {'last_letter': word[-1]}           

labeled_names=([(name1,'male') for name1 in names.words('male.txt')]+ 
           (name1,'female') for name1 in names.words('female.txt')])
random.shuffle(labeled_names)

featuresets = [(gender_features(n), gender) for (n, gender) in 
labeled_names]
train_set, test_set = featuresets[1500:], featuresets[:1500]
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

#name input part
check=input('enter the name you wanna check:  ')
print(classifier.classify(gender_features(check)))
print(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set))



feedback=input('is my answer correct??? [Y/N]:  ')
if feedback=='Y':
   print('thanks')
elif feedback=='N':
def gender_features1(word):
  return {'last_letter': word[-1],
          'second_last_letter': word[-2]}
labeled_names=([(name1,'male') for name1 in names.words('male.txt')]+
     [(name1,'female') for name1 in names.words('female.txt')])
  random.shuffle(labeled_names)

     featuresets = [(gender_features1(n), gender) for (n, gender) in labeled_names]
  train_set= featuresets[:1000]
  classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
  check1=input('plz enter the name again:  ')
  print(classifier.classify(gender_features(check1)))

 else:
     print('i dnt understand this input')
```

NaiveBayesClassifier accepts feautresets but i want to retrain the classifier with the new input data each time the user inputs a name.

I have also tried taking two feature sets the second time, but i don't know how to move forward with this part.

Comment: hey can plz someone answer

Comment: May I ask, what dataset are you using ?